# how to find wheel brand

Tags: wheels

How do I find the brand/make of a bike wheel? I have been given a free bike in great condition except the front wheel is damaged. I need to replace it but can't find any markings to state what make it is.

Comment: If you're replacing the wheel, the brand is not important. Just ensure that you have the correct axle and rim size. There are further considerations depending on the type of brakes you have.

Answer (score 1):

you need to know the width of the front fork at the axle, to know what width your new hub needs to be. Then you need the diameter of the wheel (mostly stated on the tire, 26" or 28" usually) and if you need a wheel with a braking surface on the rim of the wheel (if you have v-brakes: yes). If you have a disc brake in the front, you need a compatible hub for this. With those four things in mind you can go and look for a wheel :)

Comment: Also worth noting that in some cases you may not need the exact same size of wheel.  If your bike has an old 27x1-1/4 wheel, then you can often switch it for a new 700c wheel without much trouble. This will give you more selection of wheels and tires.  Just check that the brakes have enough reach to account for the slightly smaller wheel.